# Single and Double Quotes in dynamic SQL Criteria

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am doing Data base coding based on a large quantity of driving material descriptions. A ton (Thousands) of these variables include measurements such as 1' x 4" Steel Rod for example

I can't escape the quote in the criteria SQL because my criteria is dynamic. How else can I escape the quote?

```
If IsNull(Me.part.Value) = True Then
'if no part entered, use description
Description = Me.desc.Value
'look up the data on this part
Me.Quantity.Value = Nz(DLookup("[Inventory]", "myQuery", "[myQuery]!_
[Material Description] ='" & Description & "' And [myQuery]![Dept] ='" & dept & "'"))
```

where description is from a combobox that is filled based on department such as 1' x 4" Steel Rod

EDIT: Most questions that this would be related as duplicate are looking for single quotes only such as names with single quotes whereas I have fields with several single and double quotes int he same criteria

Comment: Here are 2 solutions: 1) Use parameterized query.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059553/how-to-run-parameterized-query-from-vba-parameters-sourced-from-recordset 2) create `Parameterize` procedure that will scrub your string by replacing single and double quotes by a double version of itself.

Comment: try `REPLACE(Description,"'","''")`

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134070/dealing-with-single-quotes-in-excel-vba-sql-queries for an example of the second solution (without a procedure, just in the SQL build)

Comment: Alternatively, use my _CSql_ function listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996045/insert-order-to-ms-access-from-vb6/36997461#36997461) to concatenate the values in a structured manner.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, the replace funtion seems to eb what i am looking for. I dont ge tthe syntax error in my dlookup now, but the parameter still isnt finding the term in my domain with the new string:test1 = Me.desc.Value

    `test2 = Replace(test1, "'", "''")
    Dim DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34) 
    test1 = Replace(test2, DQ, DQ & DQ) ` @DStanley

Comment: my dlookup criteria went from 1' x 4" Steel Rod to 1'' x 4"" Steel Rod but returned no results from my domain inventory where there is definitely an entry 1' x 4" Steel Rod. do i have to replace the quotes in the domain too somehow? @DStanley

Comment: You shouldn't need to replace double-quotes within a string variable.  You'd only need to do that in a string _literal_.

Comment: @DStanley Okay, removed the double quotes code, runs through with no syntax error. Okay terrific. I should've just taken your exact advice instead of extrapolating. Thank you very much